# Prove Sequence of Functions Converges in Measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's consider a sequence of functions $f_n:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=e^{-n|1-sin(x)|}$.  Show that $f_n$ converges to $f=0$ in measure.

Attempt/Thoughts:
To prove $f_n$ converges to $f=0$ in measure, I have to show that for every $\epsilon >0$,  $\mu (x:|e^{-n|1-sin(x)|}| \geq \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  This is clear to me pictorially as seen when we graph the sequence of functions, as n gets larger and larger, the set of $x$ for which $f_n(x)$ is positive grows smaller and smaller.  The peak grows narrower and narrower.  Thus for me, it is clear pictorially that $\mu (x:|f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
[image]exactly sure how to prove this formally, any

However, I'm not exactly sure how to prove this formally/ where to begin.
I do know that $0 \leq |e^{-n|1-sin(x)|}|=|\frac{1}{e^{n|1-sin(x)|}}| \leq |1|$, but this doesn't show convergence in measure.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The estimate at the very end of your question is wrong... $|\frac{1}{e^{n|1-\sin(x)|}}| \leq |\frac{1}{e^n}|$ does **not** hold true.

Comment: @saz Oh I thought it was true because |1-sin(x)| is bounded between 0 and 2?

Comment: @saz Oh so I can only say that it is is $\leq 1$ my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just observe that $f_n \to 0 $ except at a finite number of points (the points where $\sin \, x =1$) and almost everywhere convergence implies convergence in measure.

Comment: I see, makes sense.  How would I prove formally that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ except the points where $|1-sin(x)|=0$.  It is clear that the $f_n$ goes to 1 in this case ,but how would i show in all other cases it goes to 0 (seems obvious ,but not sure how to do it formally

Comment: $e^{-nt} \to 0$ if $t >0 $; $|1-\sin\, x|>0$ except at the points where $\sin\, x=1$. In the interval $[a,b]$ there sre only finite number of points where $|1-\sin\, x|=0$ (namely, numbers of the form $(2n+1)\pi /2)$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, But how do we know that the points where sin(x)=1 forms a set of measure 0  (in order to say that we have convergence almost everywhere).

Comment: @kemb $\sin\, x=0$ iff $x=n\pi$ for some integer $n$. Any countable set has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: I don't believe this actually works because convergence in measure only implies convergence in measure if the measure space is finite

Comment: Folland states that for such to be true $\mu(X) <\infty$. How would I do this question directly from the definition of convergence in measure

Comment: @kemb Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$ is a finite measure.

Comment: But isn't the measure space R which does not have finite measure